# Create a categorical column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a table with this following relational schema.
The relational schema for this the new table is as follows:

The foreign keys for this new table are as follows:

```
Transit.{package, departDistributionCentre, departTimestamp} 
references Depart.{package, distributionCentre, timestamp}
Transit.{package, arriveDistributionCentre, arriveTimestamp} 
references Arrive.{package, distributionCentre, timestamp}
```

The table that i want to create is named Transit, with a particular column value must be one of this {“Plane”, “Car”, “Truck”}.

This is the code that i create, but apparently, the requirement to answer this question is not allowing me to insert values into table.

```
CREATE TABLE DeliveryMethod (
    MethodCode INT NOT NULL,
    Description VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (MethodCode)
);

INSERT INTO DeliveryMethod (MethodCode, Description) VALUES (1, "Plane"), (2, "Car"), (3, "Truck");

CREATE TABLE Transit (
    package VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    departDistributionCentre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    departTimestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    arriveDistributionCentre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    arriveTimestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
    method INT NOT NULL,
    cost INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (package, departDistributionCentre, departTimestamp, arriveDistributionCentre, arriveTimestamp),
    CONSTRAINT method_fk FOREIGN KEY (method) REFERENCES DeliveryMethod(MethodCode) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT depart_fk FOREIGN KEY (package, departDistributionCentre, departTimestamp) REFERENCES Depart(package, distributionCentre, timestamp) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT arrive_fk FOREIGN KEY (package, arriveDistributionCentre, arriveTimestamp) REFERENCES Arrive(package, distributionCentre, timestamp) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

any of you good people have a lead to solve this without inserting values to a table as reference?
Thanks

Comment: not allowing how? what do you try to insert?

Comment: i try to insert the categorical values into a new table, and references it in the main table as foreign key.

Comment: Insert into what table, `Transit`? ... the first 2 queries do not have trouble, but the definitions for tables `Depart` and `Arrive` are not provided, so we don't have the full picture. It seems there would be foreign key errors for the `Transit` table strictly based on what little bit is shown here.

Comment: that is the nature of foreign keys, that allows only values that are already inserted or NULL. but if this is a himework, isn't you code enough have you to provide prove of concetpt?